# React-native-google-places-autocomplete does not work in a Scroll View? VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews ERROR

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, google-places-autocomplete

This one was already discussed, but from I was able to see there is still no available solution for the issue. I have read all the documents regarding the matter. The error I am getting is: "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead" In the official documents on the plugin, it is suggested application of <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>. However, this does not fix the issue. How can I display it inside the Scroll view? Below is my code Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
export const GooglePlacesInput = () => {
  return (  
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder='Search'
      onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
        console.log(data, details);
      }}
      query={{
        key: 'my Key',
        language: 'en',
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

And I want to display it inside the scroll view

```
export const IznajmiScreen = () => ( 
  <>
  <IznajmiListContainer>
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'} >
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Naslov" /> 
      <MyDatePickerStart/>
      <MyDatePickerEnd/>
      <GooglePlacesInput/>
      </ScrollView>
  </IznajmiListContainer>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution but first do not add this,

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.']);
```

to your code. You are simply shutting up your application from warning you about errors.

Simply add "horizontal={true}" to any ScrollView wrapping your  component like this.

```
<ScrollView
   horizontal={true}
   nestedScrollEnabled={true}
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
   contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
>
   <GooglePlacesAutocomplete/>
</ScrollView>
```

Happy coding from Nigeria :).

Comment: This partically solved my issue but introduced others. I'm not sure why you made the scrollview horizontal. Once I removed that it worked.

Comment: you can also add a <ScrollView> from `react-native-virtualized-view` and pass the keyboardShouldPersistTaps.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, what worked for me is adding `disableScroll` in `GooglePlacesAutocomplete`.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
 //...
 disableScroll={true} // add this line
 //...
/>
```